# Flag was declined but the question was deleted all the same

Tags: support, flagging, deleted-questions, moderation

I flagged [this question about DD-WRT SysLog timestamps](https://serverfault.com/questions/821503/dd-wrt-syslog-wrong-time-stamp) for moderation intervention as a cross-posted question.

But the flag was declined by a moderator. Then the question was deleted "*for reasons of moderation.*" This seems disingenuous.

Comment: The flag raise on SU would not have been particularly helpful as this site is where the question fits best. If you raised a flag on SF and it was declined and then deleted then that is a question to raise on SF meta. The moderation teams are different between sites and we have no power over there.

Answer (score 6):

SF deleted it when I checked. No action was needed on SU.

As such, no moderator intervention was needed

While I do sometimes mark flags of that sort as valid, I usually take into account a few things

If there was an overlap  in scope, we need to decide which site is a better fit. In this case, its clearly superuser over serverfault.

Secondly, if I actually needed to take action - in this case, the appropriate remedial action would have been on serverfault, where the question would need to be closed/deleted.

As such, the flag *wasn't* particularly helpful and marked as such.

Answer (score 2):

Disingenious from what side of things? The [Super User version of the question you flagged](https://superuser.com/questions/1157918/dd-wrt-syslog-wrong-time-stamp) is still here. If the question is why Server Fault deleted it, it would need to be asked of them.

If the question was deleted on Server Fault, but on topic on Super User, at least by the time a moderator saw the flag, then it's a case of "this flag is noise, nothing to do here, dismiss and mark it as declined because a moderator is not required to step in" and that's that reason.

Otherwise if the flag is "this is cross-posted" then you need to include more details or at least an ask of what you want to happen. Do you want us to delete the version on Super User? Do you want us to migrate it to Server Fault so they can combine/merge it with the one there?

Comment: The question, from my flags on Super User, shows https://serverfault.com/questions/821503/dd-wrt-syslog-wrong-time-stamp.

Comment: Shows it as what? The entirety of the content of the flag, or of the question you're flagging? If it's the entirety, then that's a lot of guesswork to know why you're flagging. If it's about the question on Server Fault, that should be raised on Server Fault's meta